# Ubuntu bash scripting with root commands

Tags: bash, scripting, root

I am trying to write a bash startup script in Ubuntu 9.04 that will remove the annoying system beep from my computer:

```
#/bin/bash

rmmod pcspkr #remove system beep; also doesnt work without root access
```

it keeps coming back when I start my computer back on, and I want to run a startup script to remove this annoyance. But I do not know how to run as root in bash scripting, does anyone know how to log on as root in bash scripting?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Add this to the end of /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist:

blacklist pcspkr

This will prevent the pc speaker module from being loaded when you start the computer.

Comment: Agree, it's better to not load the module than to load and then unload it.

Answer (score -1):

1. Try `System ==> Preferences ==> Startup Applications`; You might be able to put your command right there...

   - Check this post [describing a /etc/init.d path](http://www.thekip.nl/2007/08/17/how-to-setup-startup-scripts-in-ubuntu/) for one more option
   - You could add it to the root cron job (but that will go better with a module check).

do not have a Ubuntu handy to try this now.